# Changing the indicator color in a Snackbar

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I use this library in my app:

> implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

I want to customize a **Snackbar** and add **TextView** and **ProgressBar** to it. My code is this:

```
Snackbar loadingSnackBar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.main_viewpager), R.string.loading, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
TextView tv = loadingSnackBar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
loadingSnackBar.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
ViewGroup contentLay = (ViewGroup) tv.getParent();
AVLoadingIndicatorView indicator = new AVLoadingIndicatorView(getContext());
indicator.setIndicator("BallPulseIndicator");
indicator.setIndicatorColor(R.color.orange);
contentLay.addView(indicator, 100, 100);
```

**Snackbar** shows correctly with **TextView** and **ProgressBar** but the color of **indicator** is purple, not orange.
What should I do to change **indicator**'s color to orange?

Comment: Happening with all colors or only with orange?

Comment: Happening with All colors.

Answer (score 1):

I can not change color programmatically. So I create my_indicator.xml like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
        app:indicatorColor="@color/orange"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and add it to my **Snackbar** like that:

```
View snackView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
contentLay.addView(snackView);
```

This way is ok but if you can find a solution to change color programmatically tell me, please!

Comment: Above indicated in what is your mistake

Answer (score 0):

Could you try by switching the order:

```
indicator.setIndicatorColor(R.color.orange);
indicator.setIndicator("BallPulseIndicator");
```

Alternatively, "app:indicatorColor" can set the color

```
<com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
    android:id="@+id/avi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  //or your custom size
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  //or your custom size
    style="@style/AVLoadingIndicatorView"// or AVLoadingIndicatorView.Large or AVLoadingIndicatorView.Small
    android:visibility="visible"  //visible or gone
    app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"//Indicator Name
    app:indicatorColor="your color"
    />
```

Referenced from [AVLoadingIndicatorView](https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView).

Comment: I want to use indicator programmatically not in XML.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: indicator.setIndicatorColor(R.color.orange);
indicator.setIndicator("BallPulseIndicator"); not helping :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
indicator.setIndicatorColor(R.color.orange);
```

on

```
indicator.setIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.orange));
```

And everything will work! Good luck!